# Identifying a component in a power supply, and how to check if it's faulty

Tags: power-supply, switches, identification

I have a power supply that only works when the room is very warm. I narrowed it down to one green component with a 15 on top by heating and cooling. When this component is heated the psu works and when cooled it doesn't.

What is the component and how do I test it to see if it's faulty?

[image]

[image: Bigger picture]

Comment: Can we get a bigger pic?

Can you take it out of the board and measure resistance (also as you heat it)? Also, can you trace the surrounding circuitry and sketch it? Is it on primary or secondary side, and where is it placed?

Comment: The form is similar to an unshielded wound core which has a strong PTC resistance and NTC inductance this reducing Q during light loads significantly L/DCR is my best guess

Comment: Here are some bigger pics. https://www.flickr.com/photos/53447058@N05/42369775651/in/dateposted-public/    https://www.flickr.com/photos/53447058@N05/41467199415/in/dateposted-public/   I will take the board out tomorrow again and measure the resistance of the component. If you need better pics I can take them tomorrow if you need to see more. Thanks Andy

Comment: It looks like a simple inductor, I would not look there for the fault first.  However as you have two of the components I would swap them around and see if your symptoms change, very low cost test.

Comment: _"I narrowed it down to one green component with a 15 on top by heating and cooling"_ How? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

The component does look like an inductor to me. One possibility is that there is a bad solder connection to the component. Use something nonconducting, like a wooden pencil or plastic pen, to wiggle the component around in various directions. If the supply works sometimes when you do that then you probably just need to reflow the solder connections.

Answer (score 0):

*When this component is heated the psu works and when cooled it doesn't.*

Many PSUs use a PTC at the input for limiting the inrush current at startup. For proper operation of the supply the PTC needs to heat up so that it will have a low resistance and the current is passed through, the supply works.

You cooling it down means the PTC's resistance increases, the current cannot pass and the supply switches off.

So your conclusion that this is the faulty component might be entirely wrong, the behavior you see is how it should behave.

The general advise with power supplies is to **not repair** but to **replace it**. You have to be a power supply expert to be able to properly repair a supply which doesn't behave as it should. Do you really want to risk your repair to cause a fire?